# How can I get my USB WiFi Adapter working for my installation?

Tags: system-installation, wifi

I am trying to install elementary OS Freya to my desktop PC at home.

I have a Netgear WNDA3100v3 USB WiFi adapter that does not appear to be PNP with Freya. The apartment I live in does not have any support for wired network connections.

How can I get elementary OS to recognize the WiFi adapter so I can connect to the network and install?

Edit: I have used `lsusb` and determined my device ID with the following line:

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0846:9014 Netgear, Inc.
```

On my laptop, I found [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20191003054025/https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Netgear_WNDA3100v3) and to followed the link there to the Netgear page with a standalone `installer.exe` and downloaded it, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: First of all you do not need internet connection to install elementary OS but as to  Netgear WNDA3100v3 I had the very same Netgear adapter and it was living nightmare, the solution was to install ndiswrapper (wrapper around windows adapter drivers) and use windows drivers (that was challenging as well with no windows machine, and you had to use like XP version or something, wine installation failed) but never worked quite well (connection drops, weak signal). After doing it once I was forced to reinstall my OS and I ended up just buying new adapter from company better supporting linux.

Comment: I think netgear usb wifi adapter are supported in the kernel. I use one and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

There is no support for that chipset in the Linux kernel, but you can try to build one yourself.

Source: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7727920.html

Comment: You can try too https://github.com/openwrt/mtk-wifi-gpl